# Can't restore files structure with git reset

Tags: git

I changed file directories structure in my project and now when I do `git reset --hard 514c98bd` I do get my files as they were at `514c98bd` commit, but not the directories structure.

I changed directories structure via IDE and now it's completely a mess, it's impossible to get everything as before by hands. Why git doesn't restore files as they were in directories and if it does - how can I do it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have extra files present?  If so, try "git clean -dfx" to do a hard clean (including directories, force removal, remove .gitignored files).  Also: please be more specific about your problem.  "but not the directories structure" tells us that you don't have what you expect; it does not tell us what you have **or** what you expected.